# Saving a generated thumbnail gives Object reference not set exception

Tags: c#, thumbnails

How do I save a generated thumbnail? I am getting this error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

This is my code. I am new to C#. I found the thumbnail generation code online and I thought I could use it but its giving me an error...

```
//1. <lcFilename> as path of large size file.
//2. <lnWidth> as width of required thumbnail.
//3. <lnHeight> as height of required thumbnail.
//The function returns a Bitmap object of the changed thumbnail image which you can save on the disk.
public static Bitmap CreateThumbnail(string lcFilename, int lnWidth, int lnHeight)
{
    System.Drawing.Bitmap bmpOut = null;
    try
    {
        Bitmap loBMP = new Bitmap(lcFilename);
        ImageFormat loFormat = loBMP.RawFormat;

        decimal lnRatio;
        int lnNewWidth = 0;
        int lnNewHeight = 0;

        //*** If the image is smaller than a thumbnail just return it
        if (loBMP.Width < lnWidth && loBMP.Height < lnHeight)
            return loBMP;

        if (loBMP.Width > loBMP.Height)
        {
            lnRatio = (decimal)lnWidth / loBMP.Width;
            lnNewWidth = lnWidth;
            decimal lnTemp = loBMP.Height * lnRatio;
            lnNewHeight = (int)lnTemp;
        }
        else
        {
            lnRatio = (decimal)lnHeight / loBMP.Height;
            lnNewHeight = lnHeight;
            decimal lnTemp = loBMP.Width * lnRatio;
            lnNewWidth = (int)lnTemp;
        }
        bmpOut = new Bitmap(lnNewWidth, lnNewHeight);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpOut);
        g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, 0, lnNewWidth, lnNewHeight);
        g.DrawImage(loBMP, 0, 0, lnNewWidth, lnNewHeight);

        loBMP.Dispose();
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }

    return bmpOut;
}
                    // Thumbnail Generate
                    string largefilepath = "images/" + imageuploaded;
                    string largefilepath2 = "images/users/" + imageuploaded + "-160x160";
                    Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(CreateThumbnail(largefilepath, 160, 160));
                    bmp1.Save(largefilepath2);
```

Comment: You need to use proper XML comments for documenting your methods.

Comment: At what line you got such error?

Answer (score -1):

You have to `Dispose` your `Graphics` after it finishes its job. When you draw something on an image with `Graphics`, it is common to use `using` block but since it is already in the `try/catch` scope, it seems redundant here.

```
//1. <lcFilename> as path of large size file.
//2. <lnWidth> as width of required thumbnail.
//3. <lnHeight> as height of required thumbnail.
//The function returns a Bitmap object of the changed thumbnail image which you can save on the disk.
public static Bitmap CreateThumbnail(string lcFilename, int lnWidth, int lnHeight)
{
    System.Drawing.Bitmap bmpOut = null;
    try
    {
        Bitmap loBMP = new Bitmap(lcFilename);
        ImageFormat loFormat = loBMP.RawFormat;

        decimal lnRatio;
        int lnNewWidth = 0;
        int lnNewHeight = 0;

        //*** If the image is smaller than a thumbnail just return it
        if (loBMP.Width < lnWidth && loBMP.Height < lnHeight)
            return loBMP;

        if (loBMP.Width > loBMP.Height)
        {
            lnRatio = (decimal)lnWidth / loBMP.Width;
            lnNewWidth = lnWidth;
            decimal lnTemp = loBMP.Height * lnRatio;
            lnNewHeight = (int)lnTemp;
        }
        else
        {
            lnRatio = (decimal)lnHeight / loBMP.Height;
            lnNewHeight = lnHeight;
            decimal lnTemp = loBMP.Width * lnRatio;
            lnNewWidth = (int)lnTemp;
        }
        bmpOut = new Bitmap(lnNewWidth, lnNewHeight);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpOut);
        g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, 0, lnNewWidth, lnNewHeight);
        g.DrawImage(loBMP, 0, 0, lnNewWidth, lnNewHeight);

        // Dispose Graphics so that it releases all the resources it's holding to draw on that image.
        g.Dispose();

        /* or you could use Graphics as below.. but it seems redundant, because it is already in the try / catch block.
        using ( Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpOut))
        {
            g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, 0, lnNewWidth, lnNewHeight);
            g.DrawImage(loBMP, 0, 0, lnNewWidth, lnNewHeight);
        }
        */

        loBMP.Dispose();
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }

    return bmpOut;
}
                    // Thumbnail Generate
                    string largefilepath = "images/" + imageuploaded;
                    string largefilepath2 = "images/users/" + imageuploaded + "-160x160";
                    Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(CreateThumbnail(largefilepath, 160, 160));
                    bmp1.Save(largefilepath2);
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is you have a try..catch inside your method and this is swallowing the exception, and you are returning null from there, Hence the exception that you have reported.

Option 1
My suggestion is to either do something with the exception such as log it, this way you know something went wrong, like now. And handle the instance where a null value can be returned by the method, as follows:

```
    string largefilepath = "images/" + imageuploaded;
    string largefilepath2 = "images/users/" + imageuploaded + "-160x160";
    Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(CreateThumbnail(largefilepath, 160, 160));

    if (bmp1 == null) {
        // there was an exception, check the logs
    }
    else {
        bmp1.Save(largefilepath2);
    }
```

Option 2:
Or remove the try catch completely from the method and move it out as follows:

Note: the following code assumes you have removed the try...catch from the CreateThumbnail method.

```
try {
    //Where imageUploaded is the name of the image with the extension, e.g. "samplePic.jpg"
    string largefilepath = @"c:\images\" + imageuploaded;
    string largefilepath2 = @"c:\images\users\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(imageuploaded)  + "-160x160" + System.IO.Path.GetExtension(largefilepath);
    Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(CreateThumbnail(largefilepath, 160, 160));
    bmp1.Save(largefilepath2);
} 
catch (Exception ex) {
    //do something with the exception
}
```

Comment: I have tried the second option and I got the message "Parameter is not valid"...tried debugging but cant still point out where the issue is...please help this is my first project in c#...thanks for your help

Comment: I have updated the sample code, it works. The original answer answered your question. You received a different error after that. Anyways, I have tested the code and it works. Please could you test this and let us know the value of imageUploaded you are using, also please use absolute paths.